# Multiple Category Sources Field

Tags: plugin-development, categories, craft3, field, custom-fieldtype

I want to utilise the Category field type but with the ability to choose from multiple category sources (as with Entries).

I noted in `cms/src/fields/Categories.php` that `$this->allowMultipleSources` is set to false. What is the simplest way of changing this to true without changing the source file?

Can I create a custom field that essentially just extends the original Category field but with `$this->allowMultipleSources` set to true?

Answer (score 1):

Isnt this possible with the `modifyCategorySources` hook?

-> https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#modifyentrysources-modifycategorysources-modifyassetsources-modifyusersources

I'm assuming you are using C3 by the namespace you mentioned. Correct me if this is wrong :).

Comment: Not entirely sure that is quite what am after. Want to create a new field type (rather than globally affect existing one) so that multiple category sources can be specified. Does that make sense?

Comment: Suppose really wondering whether you can `extends BaseRelationField` for your field as is the case with the existing Element Type fields

Answer (score 1):

Got there in the end and very simply through:

```
use Craft;
use craft\fields\BaseRelationField;
use craft\elements\Category;

class Categories extends BaseRelationField
{

    public static function displayName(): string
    {
        return Craft::t('app', 'Categories (multiple)');
    }

    protected static function elementType(): string
    {
        return Category::class;
    }

    public static function defaultSelectionLabel(): string
    {
        return Craft::t('app', 'Add a category');
    }
}
```

So simple